# NHibernate LINQ query with GroupBy

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I am struggling with converting SQL to NHibernate HQL.

SQL Query

```
SELECT Posts.id, Count(Comments.id) FROM Posts LEFT JOIN Comments ON Posts.id=Comments.fk_post GROUP BY Posts.id
```

LINQ

```
Session.Query<Post>().Fetch(x => x.Comments).GroupBy(x => x.id, x => x.Comments)
                .Select(x => new { PostId = x.Key, CommentCount = x.Single().Count }).ToList();
```

This is still failing with exception:
*Parameter 'inputInfo' has type 'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSingleValueInfo' when type 'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSequenceInfo' was expected.*

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have tables of `Posts` and `Comments`. There is a one-to-many relation between Posts and Comments: every Post has zero or more Comments, every Comment belongs to exactly one Post, namely the Post that the foreign key `Comments.fk_post` refers to.

You want to fetche the Id of every Post, together with the number of Comments for this Post.

Whenever you need to select "items with their zero or more sub-items", like Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders, or in your case Posts with their Comments, consider to use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin).

You can also see that a GroupJoin is the most obvious solution, if you see a SQL Left Outer Join followed by a GroupBy.
Whenever you see a SQL left outer join followed by a GroupBy, it is almost certain that you need a GroupJoin.

If you want something else than juse "items with their sub-items", use the overload that has a parameter resultSelector.

I don't know nHibernate, I assume that `Session`, `Query`, `Fetch` are used to get the IQueryables. As this is not part of the question, I leave it up to you to get the IQueryables:

```
IQueryable<Post> posts = ...
IQueryable<Comment> comments = ...

// GroupJoin Posts with Comments
var postIdsWithCommentsCount = posts.GroupJoin(comments,

post => post.Id,               // from every Post take the primary key
comment => comment.fk_post,    // from every Comment take the foreign key to Post

// parameter resultSelector: from every Post, with all its zero or more Comments,
// make one new
(post, commentsOfThisPost) => new
{
    Id = post.Id,
    Count = commentsOfThisPost.Count(),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```cs
var query = 
    from p in Session.Query<Post>()
    from c in p.Comments.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group c by p.Id into g
    select new 
    {
        PostId = g.Key,
        CommentCount = g.Sum(x => (int?)c.Id == null ? 0 : 1)
    }

var result = query.ToList();;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had to only change g.Sum(x => c.Id into .Sum(x => x.Id
Is it possible to change generated inner join into left join?